# Print A2 on A1 rolle

Tags: printing, epson, cups-lpd

I want to print a2 format on the Epson SC-T3100X printer on which the 594mm a1 roll is loaded. When printing the A2 format (594x420), it is printed vertically [This is how it is printed now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNSx3.jpg), which means that in the end the printed sheet is 594mmx594mm in size. But I would like it to be printed horizontally so that the printed sheet is 594mm high and 420mm wide:
[As it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WBis.jpg).
[This driver is installed](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=103813&DSCCHK=4614127be8ffeef28687e978224235fe7430a860).
I made some changes in ppd file but without result

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Lenovo ThinkPad E580 (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U/ 8Gb RAM)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Lenovo ThinkPad E580 (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U/ 8Gb RAM)

Comment: Please check - https://askubuntu.com/help/asking - to get acquainted with Askubuntu, note the subjects in the left side panel.

Answer (score 1):

The printer test page will likely continue to print as shown, regardless of what you do - I have not ever attempted to change that.
*Though:

You might be succesful with Settings > Printers > your_printer: *cogwheel_icon* > Orientation: Landscape*

In e.g. GIMP's Print dialog `/Page setup\`-tab you have an option "Orientation:" which you can set to Landscape - this is more likely to produce the result you expect - for the image you have loaded into GIMP.

Then, the `/Image settings\` tab will allow you to specify image size and placement on paper.

No need to alter the ppd.

https://www.gimp.org

Comment: Thank you! I have added details above!

Comment: Slightly updated to emphasize things you need to check - to get full width output.